# Are two matrices of the same rank similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that if two matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar implies that they have the same rank.

However, if they have the same rank are they similar?

Comment: please can someone help me?

Comment: Are you looking for a proof? Or will a counterexample suffice?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$ are not similar.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen darn it, I was just typing that haha

Comment: No, but if they are of the same size, they are congruent by Gaussian elimination. Not that bad.

Comment: Two matrices are *equivalent* ($A=MBN$, for some $M,N$ invertible) iff they have the same rank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by the others, the answer is negative. Actually we can say something more: if $n\ge2$, then for any $n\times n$ nonzero matrix $A$, there is ***always*** a dissimilar matrix $B$ of the same rank; if $n=1$, the statement also holds when the characteristic of the field is not $2$.

*Proof.* The case $n=1$ is trivial. Suppose $n\ge2$. Let $k=\operatorname{rank}(A)$. If $A$ is not diagonalisable, let $B$ be a diagonal matrix of rank $k$. If $A$ is diagonalisable, let $B$ be the direct sum of a $k\times k$ Jordan block for eigenvalue $1$ and a zero block.

Comment: "when the characteristic of the field is not $2$": It would still be true if "characteristic" were replaced with "cardinality".

Answer (score 1):

No not necessarily. To find a counterexample, just take any set of matrices with distinct eigenvalues, but have the same number of non-zero eigenvalues.